# Nodejs Session issue with www and non-www

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, session, https

I have following condition

(1) if i visit https://example.com 
     if goes to login page.

(2) Same if i visit to https://www.example.com 
    it goes to login page

Now I  logged  from https://example.com it redirect to dashboard page which is fine.
and again when i visit https://example.com it redirect me to dashboard page.

**Now Problem** when i visit https//www.example.com it redirect to login page.

this means i am able to login two sessions

1) https://example.com
2) https://www.example.com 
on same browser. ?

How to handle this one please .

I am using http redirect as well.

```
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    res.writeHead(301, { "Location": "https://www." + req.headers['host'] + req.url });
    res.end();
}).listen(80);
var secureServer = https.createServer(sslOptions,app).listen(443, function(err,result){

   console.log("Express server listening on port : 443");
    console.log("Mode : " + app.get('mode'));
});
```

Any suggestions ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just don't host your site on multiple hostnames. Pick one to be canonical and redirect (with a `301` HTTP response) all requests from the other to it.